# Expression- hope you'll recover from financial problem

Tags: expressions

I would like to express sorry for the financial problem a company is facing and wish and hope for success.

Basically, the former company where I used to work has sent me a letter stating that "since the company is going through financial problems they are unable to release my salary for the last month of my with with them. So I would like to ask for my salary and at the end of letter would like to say that I am sorry for the financial problems they are facing.

How do I do that? What is a good way to say it?

Comment: There could be dozens of ways! Still - *I feel sorry about your financial loss/condition. But things certainly change you know. You'll come out ahead. Don't worry, all the best.*

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as opinion based. There are lots of ways to express the idea, but the question is asking for a way to express it, not the best way.

Comment: Yes there can be many ways, but I am interested in any one way. This can help other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lots of way to express your speech concerning feeling sorry for financial burden of an organization or a company that has been in it however if I were in your shoes I would like to say like this *I am* *hopeful you will land a better situation and be loaded* *again like all the time you were in* . Again it depends on you how and whatever you want to say as a nonnative I told you something.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers here are too colloquial. You should always be formal in business correspondence. 
"Be loaded" (especially) and "You'll come out ahead" are too colloquial.
Also, "like all the time" isn't correct. Perhaps High means "like the time that..." or "as before."

You want to be formal. "I am sorry about the financial situation" is really the best thing to say.

Source: native American English speaker